# How can I get "YOUR_URL" for log in API?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm just started  for developing the facebook mobile application. 
Currently.. I'm testing the facebook login with  mobile application(my test code).

I don't know  what is the  "YOUR_URL"  for below  request  URL..

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

Q. What is the "YOUR_URL" ?  And  how can I get  "YOUR_URL"?

- I'm already have  the AppID..  but I don't how can I get the "YOUR_URL".

Answer (score 0):

YOUR_URL is where you want Facebook to redirect to after the user is authenticated.

Comment: ry0onki can you be more specific? I'm an admin on several pages and replaced YOUR_URL with the full url of the page i'd like the new tab to be added to and it just redirected to that page without adding the app.

Comment: Hi Brad, you are talking about new tabs on Facebook?  YOUR_URL is where Facebook will go after authenticating, in other words it's the last step of the auth procedure and doesn't have anything to do with tabs on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

YOUR_URL should be the url you specified in the Page-Tab settings (on developers.facebook.com) under Page-Tab-Url.